# Why can't I trigger a click event on a hyperlink through code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a manual click event on a hyper-link using jquery but I am not getting how to do it..

Here is my sample fiddle link [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/akki/XyVDd/1/

```
<input type="text" class="example" id="opval" value="back">
<a id="sub_name" href="http://www.google.co.in">abc</a>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  if($('#opval').val() =='back') {

     $('#sub_name').click();
     //$('#qwe').find('a').trigger('click');
}
    $('#sub_name').click(function(){
    alert(hi)
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a security measure. Also reduces click fraud for ads and SEO.

Comment: Using jQuery you can simulate a click event on a link but it will not replace the user click. It will call the registered event handlers but may not do the default action associated with the element

Answer (score 1):

A few minor problems here:
1. You don't have jQuery loaded in your fiddle.
2. You need to have `"hi"` in quotes in your `alert()`.

The main thing though is that you're triggering the click event before your click handler is attached. Just move the handler code to before the click trigger:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#sub_name').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
  });
  if($('#opval').val() =='back') {
    $('#sub_name').click();
  }   
});
```